# how to use docker logs to print all (including stderr) from the container

Tags: docker, logging, containers

when I run the application into the container, I can see this output:

**docker logs  3aee2bd90da4**

```
> Dot-Service initializing with env_type: CA [2018-01-11
> 09:47:30,487][16:MainProcess][webapps.py:102][INFO] DAS-conductor
> initialized with settings CAConfig
```

Now, from the docker instance, I see only the "stdout":

**root@3acd2bd90da4:/usr/src/app# ./bin/run.sh**

```
Dot-Service initializing with env_type: CA
[2018-01-11 09:47:30,487][16:MainProcess][webapps.py:102][INFO] DAS-conductor initialized with settings CAConfig
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/src/app/bin/..//run.py", line 25, in <module>
    cmd_main()
  File "/usr/src/app/bin/..//run.py", line 22, in cmd_main
```

it misses the error section beginning by "Traceback" (stderr) from the docker logs command

what could I do to print all the log as it appears when I run the command inside the container?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understood the question correctly, you can always put your application logs to Docker container logs by using below code snippet in your Dockerfile -

```
RUN ln -sf /dev/stdout /app/out/access.log \
        && ln -sf /dev/stderr /app/out/error.log
```

You need to make sure your application writes the output to respective files & you will be able to see them in your container logs. Official Nginx docker image does the same.

Ref - https://github.com/nginxinc/docker-nginx/blob/8921999083def7ba43a06fabd5f80e4406651353/mainline/jessie/Dockerfile#L21-L23

Comment: I want to see with **docker logs** command the same log as I can see into the container (when I run the application  ./bin/run.sh including the  `Traceback ....` output). **docker logs** prints only a part of the output

Comment: Exactly, you need to write those output/error in your log fie & create a symlink to stdout & stderr which gets spit by `docker log` . Something like `ln -sf /dev/stdout /app/out/access-error.log \ && ln -sf /dev/stderr /app/out/access-error.log` in Dockerfile & do `./run.sh >> /app/out/access-error.log` during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to follow the log output, and not seeing only last lines of output, use:  $docker logs -f 
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/logs/